# Sufficient conditions for the existence of the Cauchy Principal Value

Tags: real-analysis, complex-integration

I am searching for sufficient conditions for the convergence of the Principal Value Integral $$I= \text{lim}_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\biggl[\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon} dx \frac{f(x)}{x}+\int_{\epsilon}^\infty dx \frac{f(x)}{x}\biggr] $$

I know that the Principal Value is a tempered distribution. So this limit exits when acting on Schwarz space.

I also know continuity at $x=0$ is too weak an assumption.

My question then is :

If f(x) is known to be :

a) Continuous everywhere on the real line

b) Absolutely integrable and

c) Uniformly bounded

Can I conclude this limit exists? If not, is it known what additional assumptions need to be made for this to exist? (Note in my case of interest, $f(x)$ is not necessarily differentiable.)

Comment: What happens if $f$ has compact support,  is even about $0$, and for all $\epsilon>0$, $\left|\int_\epsilon^\infty f(x)\,dx\right|<\infty$

Answer (score 1):

As a counterexample, define $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ piecewise by $f(x)=-\frac{1}{\log(x)}$ for $x\in(0,e^{-1})$, then $f(x)=\frac{1}{(ex)^2}$ for $x\in[e^{-1},+\infty)$ and  $f(x)=0$ for $x\le0$. Then, $f\in L^1\cap L^\infty \cap C^0$ but from $$\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0^+}\int_\varepsilon^{1/e}\frac{-1}{x\log(x)}=+\infty,$$ you get that the principal value integral in $0$ of $f$ is equal to $+\infty$.

Comment: So without additional assumptions (Holder/Lipschitz continuity or differentiablity), no general statement can be made about this limit for just continuous integrable functions?

Comment: What happens if $f$ has compact support,  is even about $0$, and for all $\epsilon>0$, $\left|\int_\epsilon^\infty f(x)\,dx\right|<\infty$?

Comment: The principal value is trivially zero on even functions

Comment: @Cauchy: actually, it is enough to require that $f\in L^1$ and $f$ is absolutely continuous in a neighboorhood of 0 and $(f(-\varepsilon)-f(\varepsilon))\log⁡(\varepsilon)\rightarrow0, \varepsilon\rightarrow0^+$ as you can see by integrating by parts

Comment: @Bob : I can actually see your point. The problem is my function is somewhat abstractly defined. So it is quite difficult to explicitly check for local conditions of the sort given by your third point. I was actually hoping for more global conditions which would automatically force the behaviour needed to make the principal value finite. And I was looking for the weakest such condition. But thanks for the nice counter example!

Comment: are you sure that you are interested in the behavior in a single point? Does your problem appear in the context of convolution between the principal value integral distribution and some function and so what you actually need is that your convolution is defined at least almost everywhere?

Comment: Oh. Its definitely a single point. Not the convolution.